# IAP: Receives `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` callback with unfinished transactions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Some times I get this callback

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
```

Even before I receive this

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

I don't even get to say `finishTransaction:`. I find this superweird. I've all this time been assuming `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` wouldn't be triggered before I had marked every unfinished transaction as finished.

Is this expected behavior?

This is what I found in documentation

> `- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue
>   *)queue Description` 
>   Tells the observer that the payment queue has finished sending restored transactions. This method is called after
>   all restorable transactions have been processed by the payment queue.
>   Your application is not required to do anything in this method.

I'm not sure what it means.

Answer (score 0):

I found the header file itself to be most clear on this part.

```
@interface SKPaymentQueue : NSObject
...
// Array of unfinished SKPaymentTransactions.  Only valid while the queue has observers.  Updated asynchronously.
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *transactions;

@end

@protocol SKPaymentTransactionObserver
// Sent when all transactions from the user's purchase history have successfully been added back to the queue.
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
...
@end
```

These two in conjunction make it unambiguous. 
`paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` is triggered once `StoreKit` has added all transactions to `SKPaymentQueue`. `-[SKPaymentQueue transactions]` only has a list of unfinished transactions.

I think the docs could have been more clear about this.